# running script to upload file to AWS S3 works, but running the same script via jenkins job doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-s3, ssh

**The simple goal:**

I would like to have two containers both running on my local machine. One `jenkins` container & one `SSH server` container. Then, jenkins job could connect to the SSH server container & execute aws command to upload file to S3.

**My workspace directory structure:**

- a `docker-compose.yml` (details see below)
- a directory named `centos/`,
- Inside `centos/` I have a `Dockerfile` for building the SSH server image.

**The docker-compose.yml:**

In my `docker-compose.yml` I declared the two containers(services).

- One jenkins container, name `jenkins`.
- One SSH server contaienr, named `remote_host`.

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      - net

  remote_host:
    container_name: remote_host
    image: remote-host
    build: 
      context: centos7
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

The `Dockerfile` for the `remote_host` is like this (Notice the last `RUN` installs the AWS CLI):

```
FROM centos

RUN yum -y install openssh-server

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo remote_user:1234 | chpasswd && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh/ && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN ssh-keygen -A
RUN rm -rf /run/nologin

RUN yum -y install unzip

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && unzip awscliv2.zip && ./aws/install
```

**Current situation with the above setup:**

I run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`. Both `jenkins` container and the `remote_host`(SSH server) container are up and running successfully.

**I can** go inside `jenkins` container by :

```
$ docker exec -it jenkins bash
jenkins@7551f2fa441d:/$
```

**I can** successfully ssh to the `remote_host` container by:

```
jenkins@7551f2fa441d:/$ ssh -i /tmp/remote-key remote_user@remote_host
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'remote_host' differs from the key for the IP address '172.19.0.2'
Offending key for IP in /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Matching host key in /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts:2
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
[remote_user@8c203bbdcf72 ~]$
```

Inside the `remote_host` container, I have also configured my AWS access key and secret key under `~.aws/credentials`:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

**I can** successfully run aws command to upload a file from `remote_host` container to my AWS S3 bucket. Like:

```
[remote_user@8c203bbdcf72 ~]$ aws s3 cp myfile s3://mybucket123asx/myfile
```

**What the issue is**

Now, I would like my jenkins job to execute the aws command to upload file to S3.  So I created a shell script inside my `remote_host` container, the script is like this:

```
#/bin/bash
BUCKET_NAME=$1
aws s3 cp /tmp/myfile s3://$BUCKET_NAME/myfile
```

In my jenkins, I have configured the SSH & in my jenkins job configuration, I have:

[image]

As you can see , it simply runs the script located in the `remote_host` container.

When I build the jenkins job, I always get the error in console : `upload failed: ../../tmp/myfile to s3://mybucket123asx/myfile Unable to locate credentials`.

Why the same s3 command works when executing in the `remote_host` container but not working when run from jenkins job?

I also tried explicitly export the aws key id & secrete key in the script. (bear in mind that I have the `~.aws/credentils` configured in `remote_host`, which works without explicitly exporting the aws secret key)

```
#/bin/bash
BUCKET_NAME=$1
export aws_access_key_id=AKAARXL1CFQNN4UV5TIO
export aws_secret_access_key=MY_SECRETE_KEY
aws s3 cp /tmp/myfile s3://$BUCKET_NAME/myfile
```

Comment: For the last example, the export should be in capital letters as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html).

Comment: For the jenkins, its possible that that the scripts do not run `remote_user` user. In your script, can you add `whoami` and confirm the user which executes the script?

Comment: Most likely the user problem, as mentioned by Marcin. By the way, your scripts are missing an exclamation mark in the top line: it should be `#!/bin/bash`. This of course isn't the root of the problem with upload.

Comment: I tried @Marcin 's suggestion, the `whoami` shows that jenkins runs the script as `remote_user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I solved my issue by changing the `export` statement to capital case. So, the cause of the issue is that when jenkins run the script, it runs as `remote_user` on `remote_host`. Though on `remote_host` I have the `~/.aws/credentials` setup, but that file only have read permission for users other than `root`:

```
[root@8c203bbdcf72 /]# ls -l ~/.aws/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112 Sep 25 19:14 credentials
```

That's why when jenkins run the script to upload file to S3 got `Unable to locate credentials` failure. Because the credentials file can't be read by `remote_user`. So, I have to still uncomment the lines which exports aws key id and secret key. @Marcin's comment is helpful that the letters need to be capital letters, otherwise it would not work.

So, overall, what I did to fix the issue is to update my script with:

```
export aws_access_key_id=AKAARXL1CFQNN4UV5TIO
export aws_secret_access_key=MY_SECRETE_KEY
```